# Is importing to Aperture then editing in iMovie a viable workflow?

Tags: mac, imovie

I'm primarily a still photographer, but necessity is pushing me into learning video editing. I'm in the habit of dumping my camera data to Aperture, using the rating & stacking system there to sort out favorite pictures, and finally exporting those for final touches in PhotoShop.

Will a similar workflow work for iMovie and editing there? iMovie automatically picks up the videos I dump into Aperture, but at first glance I don't see the precious, precious metadata I've taken the time to mark them up with there: No ratings!

Is there a way to get ratings/sorting from Aperture showing up in iMovie? If not, what's your favorite workflow for picking clips to use in iMovie?

Answer (score 1):

I usually manually drop my files into the iMovie Drop Box for safe keeping until I want to use/edit them and do all my managing of videos (personal ones, at least) in iMovie.